# How to tell this Java method to execute itself again under a certain condition?

Tags: java, stdout, stdin

Please refer to this UVa OJ problem: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=27&page=show_problem&problem=2595

It's working for a single test case. However, there is no given input for the number of test cases, which means that the program should know when to continue and when to stop just by reading the input for the variables of the problem

I'm think about using the `scanner.hasNextLine()`method as a conditional; and if it's true, make main start again, but I'm not sure how to do it. Any clue?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    int B = scanner.nextInt();
    int H = scanner.nextInt();
    int W = scanner.nextInt();
    int [] priceArray = new int [H];
    int [] availableBeds = new int [W];
    int cheapestStay = 999999999;
    for (int i=0; i<H; i++){
        priceArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int j=0; j<W; j++){
            availableBeds[j] = scanner.nextInt();
            if (availableBeds[j] >= N && priceArray[i]*N <= B && priceArray[i]*N < cheapestStay){
                cheapestStay = priceArray[i]*N;
            }

        }

    }

    if (cheapestStay != 999999999){
        System.out.println(cheapestStay);
    }else{
        System.out.println("stay home");
    }
    /*if (!scanner.hasNextLine)
        repeat*/
}
```

Comment: Wrap your business logic code in a seperate method and then call that method in `main(..)` method based on condition recall that method again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop to repeat the instructions of your main method as long as `hasNextLine()` evaluates to `true`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all the code in your `main(...)` method into a `while(scanner.hasNextLine())` loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a best usecase of do-while

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    do {

        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        int B = scanner.nextInt();
        int H = scanner.nextInt();
        int W = scanner.nextInt();
        int [] priceArray = new int [H];
        int [] availableBeds = new int [W];
        int cheapestStay = 999999999;
        for (int i=0; i<H; i++){
            priceArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();

            for (int j=0; j<W; j++){
                availableBeds[j] = scanner.nextInt();
                if (availableBeds[j] >= N && priceArray[i]*N <= B && priceArray[i]*N < cheapestStay){
                    cheapestStay = priceArray[i]*N;
                }

            }

        }

        if (cheapestStay != 999999999){
            System.out.println(cheapestStay);
        }else{
            System.out.println("stay home");
        }
        /*if (!scanner.hasNextLine)
            repeat*/
    } while (scanner.hasNextLine());
}
```